# How to extract numbers from a String (with no black space) using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-requests

I have a string as the following:

```
s = 'ABC:10DEF:20'
```

I need to extract the numbers and assign it to the variables as :

```
ABC = 10
DEF = 20
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is it possible for you to source your data in a different format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest splitting the string to a dictionary where the keys are the alpha letters and the values are the numbers.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'ABC:10DEF:20'
>>> d = dict(x.split(':') for x in re.split(r'(?<=\d)(?=\D)', s))
>>> d
{'ABC': '10', 'DEF': '20'}
```

Comment: nice. this is much more elegant

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex to find all numerical values

```
import re
s = 'ABC:10DEF:20'
re.findall('[\d]{1,}',s)
```

Comment: Thanks.. this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the `.split()` built-in method in python. For example, you can say `s = s.split(":")` and what it should throw is `["ABC", "10", "DEF", "20"]`. Then it is simply using indices to find what you need. To actually assign the ABC as a variable I don't know, but I think you should start with the `.split()` hope this helps:)

Comment: I can't see how splitting with `s.split(":")` produces that list

Comment: split wont work because `'ABC:10DEF:20'` will split to `['ABC', '10DEF', '20']`